# push a view controller from selecting a row in a table view

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

So I have a UITableView where I want to push to a details controller when the row is selected.

My attempt was to:

```cs
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var controller = new BlogDetailViewController();
        navController.PushViewController(controller, true);
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
    }
```

But I am getting the complaint that `BlogDetailViewController()` takes an argument.

My `BlogDetailViewController`:

```cs
public partial class BlogDetailViewController : UIViewController
{
    public string blogTitle;

    public BlogDetailViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

}
```

What is `Intptr handle` and how do I pass it in? I tried adding a zero argument constructor and pushing to that, but when I ran the app it pushed to a black screen.

Comment: You should be able to create an empty constructor.  Was the detail controller created with Interface Builder?

Comment: @jason Ya it was added into my storyboard via xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're instantiating it from a XIB, I believe you want to use

```
UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName ("name", null);
UIViewController ctrl = (UIViewController)board.InstantiateViewController ("name");
```

Comment: `Storyboard does not exist in current context`

Comment: for `name` in `InstantiateViewController` do I need to include a .cs or something? I put `BlogDetailViewController` and its telling me the storyboard doesn't have a view with that identifier.

Comment: Got it. You need to set a `storyboard id` for the `ViewController` in xcode

Answer (score 0):

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController = view;
```

add this line also in last